# Strange error in templated constructor

Tags: c++, templates, eigen, eigen3

I am getting a strange compiler error when trying to cast an argument in a templated constructor. Here is a minimal example:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>

class Plane
{
public:
    template <typename TVector>
    Plane(const TVector& coefficients) {
        coefficients.cast<double>(); // compiler error on this line
    }

// This compiles fine
//    Plane(const Eigen::Vector3d& coefficients) {
//        coefficients.cast<double>();
//    }
};

int main(){return 0;}
```

The error is:

```
expected primary-expression before 'double'
expected ';' before 'double'
```

Since this class is never instantiated (`main()` is empty), I thought that the compiler wouldn't even see the function template at all, so I'm very confused as to how there is an error in this expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `template` keyword:

```
template <typename TVector>
Plane(const TVector& coefficients) {
    coefficients.template cast<double>();
}
```

Comment: Yep, that does it. Can you say what this is called so I can look up when I need to use it?

Comment: @DavidDoria He did. It is the [`template` keyword](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/template)

Comment: @DavidDoria see the link above your original question, which has been marked as duplicate. The link explains this phenomenon in full.